# need help to save different unique date in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating a app using django rest-framework to record mensuration date.I have to put a validation to date fields like if one date is already entered in database the app should avoid to enter same date which is already exist in database. Need help to do that

Comment: Mark the field as `unique=True`.

Comment: That will make new problem while adding new date. User have to save date monthly

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I assume the OP means unique per user, perhaps `class Meta: unique_together = (('user', 'date'),)` is more appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) where you include both the `user` and the `date`:

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'date'], name='unique_date_per_user')
        ]
```

Prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can make use of [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('user', 'date'),)
```